# One Piece song on episode 548 at around 5:12

Tags: one-piece, music

What's the song that plays in episode 548 at around 5:12? I've been searching for it everywhere, but I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: Providing a clip to the scene would be helpful. Different sources might have a different frame of reference for the time code. Without a source to establish this, it's hard to tell what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The song seems to be from the One Piece Original Soundtrack by Kouhei Tanaka (田中 公平) called "Sakusen kaishi ~ osowa reru mura ~" (作戦開始 ～襲われる村～)

Here is a youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ANaEsE5bdI